# Is there a way to capture JavaScript PageMethods calls with jQuery? (To show Loading Screen)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, pagemethods

I'd like to know if someone knows a way, using jQuery, to capture PageMethods calls made from JavaScript in order to show a loading screen when a call begins and to hide it when it ends (when the PageMethod responds).

I know there are ways to capture ajax calls when they are made like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        // Do something interesting here.
    }
});
```

but is there a way to capture them and then do something when they are called like this?

JavaScript

```
PageMethods.serverSideMethod(responseFromServer);
```

CodeBehind

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string serverSideMethod()
{
    return response;
}
```

I'm using jQuery 1.9.2, programming in C# and need this script to be compatible with IE6.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854834/jquery-ajax-calling-asp-net-page-method-how-to-return-value-back-to-jquery - see the link in the accepted answer. That should at least provide sufficient insight into the ASP.NET-AJAX model powering page methods.

Answer (score 0):

it's almost the same,use this url in jQuery

```
url: "PageName.aspx/serverSideMethod",
```

insert your method name without parantheses,it should work.

Edit:

you can capture start and complete event with using these ajax events:

```
$.ajax({
   beforeSend: function(){
     // Handle the beforeSend event
   },
   complete: function(){
     // Handle the complete event
   }
   // ......
 });
```

Then you can show or hide whatever you want... here is the full documentation: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I know, but I need to find a workaround to make it work calling the method in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just show the loading message right after or before the PageMethod call and then hide it in the callback:

```
PageMethods.serverSideMethod(responseFromServer);
//Show loading using jQuery Here

function responseFromServer(results){
    //process results
    //hide loading using jQuery
}
```

UPDATE:

Have you tried Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager beginRequest Event and endRequest Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That's the thing, I don't want to be showing and hiding it manually every time I make a PageMethod call. I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question.  Have you tried Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager beginRequest Event and endRequest Event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432(v=vs.100).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810(v=vs.100).aspx